# Node.js stream readable.read call repeatly

Tags: javascript, node.js

The question is actually asked already by [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452846/must-i-repeated-call-readable-read-within-a-readable-event-handler), but I don't find the question really answered yet. Must `readable.read()` inside a readable event handler be called repeatedly? In the current node documentation the example code read:

```
var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read())) {
    console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
  }
});
```

`readable.read()` is called repeatedly.

The document says this about readable event:

> Once the internal buffer is drained, a readable event will fire again when more data is available.

It also says this about `read()`:

> If you do not specify a size argument, then it will return all the data in the internal buffer.

So is there any case where putting it in a while loop to repeatably call `read()` necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this will cause your server to block if the read never returns null:

```
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read())) {
    console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
  }
```

Unless you specify a size argument, you only need to call read once for each time the 'readable' event is fired. If you do specify a size, and the size is smaller than the total amount of data to read, then you have to call it as many times as it's needed.

You have `readable.on('end', ...` that will allow you to know when no more data is available.

Comment: Then the example in the documentation stands corrected, I guess.

Comment: According to a talk prior to the then expected v.10 release (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3685/presentations/streams2/streams2-ko.pdf), returning null is part of the specification. , readable event is only fired after it returns null. Maybe that's why the doc use a while loop. Maybe that's why it is necessary then? Because if you don't read till it's empty then it has not returned null yet.

Comment: Anyway, the documentation certainly doesn't reflect that null must be returned by readable.read() before another readble event, only that the buffer is empty.

Answer (score 0):

in object mode, `.read()` only returns an object, so this would be necessary. i'm not sure if this is necessary for binary streams, but i've successfully only called `.read()` once per `readable` event in them.